# How do you force Combobox dropdowns to stay open

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

How do you force Combobox dropdowns to stay open even when other Alert boxes appear. Looking at what to subclass from mx.Combobox, there doesn't seem to be much that i can do to short of implementing an entire combobox from scratch.Thx

Comment: You'll have to extend it.  Somewhere there should be an event listener for either the component losing focus or mouse clicks out of the sandbox.  You just have to find those listeners and override them to not close the ComboBox.  It'll probably be tedious, but it should be doable.

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to create a custom ComboBox which if created in following Link. and might be this link will going to be useful to you.

Please visit this [LINK](http://old.nabble.com/Making-ComboBox-stay-open-after-item-select--td23069816.html)